# Access methods which are being called from another jar

Tags: java, loops, methods, jar

So I have a jar file which has a runnable, and it's calling a method named loop() every second. I want to be able to access this loop() method from ANOTHER java file.

I was wondering if this is possible? Can I access this loop method without the use of abstract?

Comment: The answer is yes, but since it seems like you are having trouble with this, I would guess that something is not quite right. Please post a code snippet of what you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the loop method is public, you can access it from another "java file".

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood what I meant. I want to be able to modify the contents of the method.

Comment: I didn't misunderstand, you misasked.